# Прочитать JSON ответ и сделать редирект

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Здрaвствуйте. Скажите, пожалуйста, можно ли при помощи jQuery написать простой редирект на основе следующего JSON ответа:

```
{
  "success": false,
  "data": {
    "message": "Forbidden"
  }
}
```

Т.е. если какой-либо скрипт возвращает данную ошибку, то jQuery-код делает перенаправление пользователя с текущей страницы, допустим, на страницу `/error`

[image]

Пример:

1. Пользователь на странице `/news`
2. Какой-либо PHP скрипт возвращает в фоне JSON-response, например: `{ "success": false }`
3. jQuery-скрипт перенаправляет пользователя со страницы `/news` на страницу `/error`, когда видит эту ошибку `{ "success": false }`

Comment: [Интерфейс Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Location)

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать универсальную вещь, если у вас все Ajax запросы могут вернуть одно и тоже:

```js
$(document).bind("ajaxComplete", (response) => {
    if (response.hasOwnProperty("success") && !response.success) {
        window.location.replace("/error");
    }
});
```

В этом коде происходит присвоение [события](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) `ajaxComplete`, который является глобальным и срабатывает после отработки Ajax. `response` - это данные ответа сервера в каком-то вашем формате. Судя по формату, можно проверить наличия ключа `success` и его ложность, то есть, если есть ключ в ответе от сервера и он равен `false`, то сделать что-то. В данном случае `window.location.replace("/error");` делает редирект на страницу `/error`.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Пишет `Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`, хотя подключается позднее jQuery (в самом подвале).

Comment: @caboke ну что-то не так с самим jQuery